# Javascript switch statements for form input

Tags: javascript, forms, input, switch-statement

Trying to learn some basic JS principles to create a delivery cost calculator based on user input forms and JS switch statements to return a price.

(I know this would be easier and more practical with a server database but I would prefer to stick to JS for now)

This is my attempt;

HTML

```
<h2>DELIVERY CHARGE CALCULATOR</h2>

<div id="size">

    <p id="step1">STEP 1</p>
    <p>DIMENSIONS</p>
    <p>WIDTH(cm):
        <input type="text" name="width" id="width" size="5" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
    <p>LENGTH(cm):
        <input type="text" name="length" id="length" size="5" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
    <p>HEIGHT(cm):
        <input type="text" name="height" id="height" size="5" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
</div>

<div id="postcode">
    <p id="step2">STEP 2</p>
    <p>Postcode area (eg. N1, N2 etc)</p>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" size="5" maxlength="3" />
</div>

<input type="button" id="button" value="GET PRICE" onClick="getDetails()">

<div id="message">
    <p><b>THANK YOU</b></p>
    <P>THE COST FOR DELIVERY FROM STORE WILL BE:</P>
    <p id="price_msg"></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#message {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#message.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

JS

```
var width;
var length;
var height;
var men;
var postcode;
var cost;

function smallVan(postcode) {
    switch (postcode) {
        case "N1":
            cost = "45";
            break;
        case "N2":
            cost = "50";
            break;
    }
    showPrice(cost);
};

function transit(postcode) {
    switch (postcode) {
        case "N1":
            cost = "80";
            break;
        case "N2":
            cost = "100";
            break;
    }
    showPrice(cost);
};

function getVehicle() {
    if (width < 100 && length < 100 && height < 100) {
        postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value.toUpperCase();
        smallVan(postcode);
    };
    else if (width > 100 || length > 100 || height > 100 {
            postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value.toUpperCase();
            transit(postcode);
        };

        function getDetails() {
            width = document.getElementById("width").value;
            length = document.getElementById("length").value;
            height = document.getElementById("height").value;
            getVehicle(width, length, height);
        };

        function showPrice(cost) {
            var msg_display = document.getElementById("message")
            msg_display.className = "show";
            var price = document.getElementById("price_msg");
            price.textContent = "£" + cost;
        };
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kussrtc/1/

The fiddle doesn't work at all, although my tested version displays the message but returns the price (var cost) as undefined?

Comment: `showPrice` is undefined since it's within the `getVehicle` scope which is not available in `smallVan`. Lot's of bad coding practice. Consider a Constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I missed the closing bracket for getVehicle so thanks for pointing that out. I will try the constructor method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here for corrections: https://jsfiddle.net/jetweedy/upvfgck2/2/

Several problems...

(1) if/else blocks weren't properly formatted (you were closing with semicolon after the 'if' part, and then putting 'else' separately and not closing that off afterwards.

(2) You had 'postcode' as an ID on a div as well as an input, so 'document.getElementById(...)' just retrieved the first one (the DIV not the input) and couldn't figure out its 'value'.

(3) Specifically in jsfiddle, if you use the 'onload' setting on the left side, then the functions that you define will only be known in the body.onload scope, so later when you click the button after the page loads, it won't find the functions. You can circumvent this two ways... either just don't use the 'onLoad' option in jsFiddle, or else add your event listener to your button in your javascript instead of in your HTML code... something like...

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = getDetails;
```

Hope that helps. I got it working-ish, but once I cleaned it up enough figure out the problems, left it alone. Hopefully the notes 1-3 made sense.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. You spotted some obvious mistakes and some I was not aware of. I added a window.onload function to add the click event Listener and it seems to work ok. Not entirely sure what you mean regarding the onload function on the left hand side? but thanks again.

Comment: Oh, just means that (in jsFiddle specifically) there's a drop-down menu in the left-hand options where you can specify whether things happen 'body.onload' or a few other options. You had 'body.onload' picked when I looked, and what that means is that everything you typed in your JS box was wrapped inside of a body.onload listener. So if was saying something like body.onload = function() { ALL YOUR CODE } .... that means that none of the functions you were defining were globally known to your HTML elements when clicked and stuff.